# Ubuntu 18.04 alternating between successful boot and failed boot

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 which has this strange behaviour:

First boot fails - black screen after grub. After a force power-off the next one succeeds. Another reboot would bring it to the first state - failed boot (and so on).

The machine is a i9-9820x (ASUS X299) with dual nvidia GPUs (1080 Ti). Boot device is nvme ssd.

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Kernel details:

```
$ uname -a
Linux sbimage1804 5.0.0-36-generic #39~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 12 11:09:50 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

A few things that were tried:

- kernel parameter: `nomodeset`: display changes accordingly but it still fails first boot
- blacklisting nouveau driver: display changed to lower resolution, first boot fails (nvidia drivers haven't been installed yet)
- Trying rescue mode on first boot: first boot hangs, last writing on the screen: `Loading initial ramdisk`
- Also didn't help: setting `recordfail=0` in grub
- kernel parameter: `acpi=off` did not help either

Any ideas of how to solve / debug this situation? I tried adding `debug earlyprintk=efi,keep` kernel parameters but it doesn't add any output before the machine hangs (even in rescue mode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems this is an issue caused by a faulty update of intel microcode (relative to the affected hardware).

Working around it is done by adding `dis_ucode_ldr` as kernel parameter. This eliminates the hanged boots.

Note that this workaround comes with a risk of missing a fix to a CPU bug. The price looks like keep following on errata/bugs relevant to the CPU model and and perform BIOS updates to the latest version in a hope that the vendor addresses those bugs. Hopefully a future update of `intel-microcode` package would fix that issue.

Edit:

I discovered that the default package of intel-microcode that comes with Ubuntu 18.04.3 doesn't cause this issue. A newer version of that packages coming from `sudo apt upgrade` is the problematic one. Marking that package as 'hold' prevents it from being upgraded, and avoids the need to put the `dis_ucode_ldr` kernel parameter:

```bsh
$ sudo apt-mark hold intel-microcode
```